# How do I enable DML logging in Cassandra 2.1?

Tags: logging, cassandra, cassandra-2.1

How to enable logging DML(inserts, updates), DDL (alter, create) operations in cassandra version 2.1?

```
nodetool getlogginglevels

Logger Name                                        Log Level
ROOT                                                    INFO
com.thinkaurelius.thrift                               ERROR
```

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: ok, sorry, here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315166/how-do-i-enable-dml-logging-in-cassandra-2-1

Comment: All good. I've responded to you on DBA Stack Exchange. Cheers!